# Taylor Approximation for Time Dilation and Lorentz Contraction

Tags: special-relativity, approximations

I don't know why the taylor expansion for the time dilation and lorentz contraction look like this. Here, the velocity $\mathbf v$ of $\overline{\mathit O}$ relative to $\mathit O$ is nearly that of light, $\vert \mathbf v \vert = 1 - \epsilon$, $0 \lt \epsilon \ll 1$.

(a) $\Delta t \approx \Delta \overline{t}/\sqrt{2\epsilon}$,

(b) $\Delta x \approx \Delta \overline{x}/\sqrt{2\epsilon}$,

For (a), I started with the formula $\Delta t = \Delta \overline{t}/\sqrt{1-v^2}$ (setting c, the velocity of light, as 1), and proceeded to use the equation for taylor expansion to find out the answer:

$$f(x) = f(x_0)+f'(x_0)(x-x_0)+\frac{f''(x_0)(x-x_0)^2}{2!}+\frac{f'''(x_0)(x-x_0)^3}{3!}+ \ ...$$

The expression I got is

$$\Delta t \approx \left.(1+v^2)^{-1/2}\right\rvert_{v=1-\epsilon} \cdot \Delta \overline{t} + \left.v(1-v^2)^{-3/2}\right\rvert_{v=1-\epsilon}(v-(1-\epsilon)) \cdot \Delta \overline{t} + \frac{1}{2} [\left.(1-v^2)^{-3/2} + 3v^2(1-v^2)^{-5/2}]\right\rvert_{v=1-\epsilon} \cdot (v-(1-\epsilon))^2 \cdot \Delta \overline{t} $$

When I substitute the numbers in, I don't see how it reduces to $\Delta t \approx \Delta \overline{t}/\sqrt{2\epsilon}$. The terms $\left.v(1-v^2)^{-3/2}\right\rvert_{v=1-\epsilon}$ and $\frac{1}{2} [\left.(1-v^2)^{-3/2} + 3v^2(1-v^2)^{-5/2}]\right\rvert_{v=1-\epsilon}$ cannot go to 0 because (1-v^2) is in the denominator. How do the later terms magically disappear?

Another problem I run into is the expression for $\Delta x \approx \Delta \overline{x}/\sqrt{2\epsilon}$. I use the formula $\Delta x = \Delta \overline{x}\sqrt{1-v^2}$ as the original formula. However, when I attempt to find the term $f(1-\epsilon)$, what I get is not $\Delta \overline{x}/\sqrt{2\epsilon}$ but $\Delta \overline{x}\sqrt{2\epsilon}$. There is something fishy because the first term already deviates from the correct answer. What do I make of it?? Is the formula $\Delta x = \Delta \overline{x}/\sqrt{1-v^2}$ then? But that would disagree with the taylor approximation of $\Delta x$ when $\mathbf v$ is close to 0, which according to a previous problem, has the approximation $\Delta x \approx (1-\frac{1}{2}v^2)\Delta \overline{x}$

Comment: Also, a comment apart from my answer: if you are interested in the asymptotic behavior as $\epsilon\to 0$, the coefficients of your expansion should be evaluated at $\epsilon = 0$. Perhaps you did not because you realized that already to zeroth order you would obtain a diverging term; this is precisely signaling that you are committing a mistake: you should first split $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon(2-\epsilon)}}$ as $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon}\sqrt{(2-\epsilon)}}$ and only expand the non-diverging factor.

Comment: Thank you for your comment!@Albert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expression $(a)$ is obtained with a zeroth order expansion. I assume we work in units where $c = 1$. In one hand you have
$$1 - (1-\epsilon)^2 = \epsilon(2-\epsilon)$$
and in the other you have
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2-\epsilon}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \mathcal{O}(\epsilon),$$
so putting both things together you obtain the following approximation for the Lorentz factor:
$$\gamma := \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(1-\epsilon)^2}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2-\epsilon}} =  \frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}\cdot\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \mathcal{O}(\epsilon)\right) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\epsilon}} + \mathcal{O}(\sqrt{\epsilon})\stackrel{\epsilon\downarrow0}{\sim}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\epsilon}}$$
where $\stackrel{\epsilon\downarrow0}{\sim}$ means that the expressions to its sides are assymptotically equivalent as $\epsilon$ approches $0$ from the positive side. This explains your expression $(a)$.

Concerning $(b)$, if $\Delta\bar{x}$ is indeed the proper length then I'd say the expression is wrong and you are right.